# Gridlayout and mouse listeners

Tags: java, user-interface, grid-layout, mouselistener

hi i am trying to build a grid-layout GUI with mouse listener. SO when a particular cell is clicked in a grid ,information would be displayed. I don't know where to start, any help would be good 
thankyou

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a class that inherits from JPanel or JFrame and there is whole GUI in it. Then, this class should implement mouseListener. Then your class should have similar code:

```
@override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}
@override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}
@override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
@override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
    /*This method is being called when you release your click. It's better
      then mouseClicked because mouseClicked is only called when you press
      and release on the same pixel or Object (not sure about it)
    */
}
@override
public void mouseExiteded(MouseEvent e){}
```

In each method you can get source of

```
MouseEvent e
```

using

```
Object source = e.getSource();
if (source == button1){
    //Do sth
}if (source == button2){
    //Do sth else
}if (source == radioButton1){
    //Do whatever you want
}
```

Then you have reference to the source, so you can modify what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your gridlayout, set all grids with some Component such as Button or Label. You can set listeners on the components added and display information when a component is clicked

Answer (score 0):

To use properly a gridbaglayout, you should first work on the **gridbagconstraints**. Then, you should use the **ActionListener** interface to handle the mouse clicks. If the cells are of the type Labels, you coud hide the text by using myLabel.**setText**("") and putting the text by using myLabel.setText("information to display"). If you need more help, just ask :D and +1 if it helps ^^